# API request object with Handle() method

Tags: web-api

This is actual production code, and I think what I have stripped out is truly irrelevant to the question. (If I'm wrong I'm sure I'll be corrected.)

This is a request object received by a .NET Web API application. Our application has dozens of them, and they each have a `Handle()` method.

I'm not the most experienced Web API developer, but to me this seems off. It seems to me that a controller should handle a request or delegate it to an orchestrator, but for a request to "handle" itself looks like a clear violation of the SRP. It also seems odd to inject dependencies into a class that should only be a container for data.

This is for my own understanding. I'm not asking anyone to settle an argument. The consultant who wrote this has moved on. So am I. He said this was the "new paradigm" for writing Web APIs. I'm just trying to understand - am I missing something, or is this a common pattern for developing Web APIs?

Thanks

```
public class GetUserRequest 
{

    IUserRepository _userRepository;
    IActiveDirectoryRepository _activeDirectoryRepository;
    IMapper _mapper;
    IAccountRepository _accountRepository;

    public GetUserRequest(IUserRepository userRepository, IMapper mapper, IAccountRepository accountRepository, IActiveDirectoryRepository activeDirectoryRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _accountRepository = accountRepository;
        _activeDirectoryRepository = activeDirectoryRepository;
    }

    public async Task<UserApiModel> Handle()
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm always hesitant to jump in to **the** new way of doing things.  Ask if he has an article that you can read to understand why this approach is recommended.  My gut says this is very heavy handed, but there may be a legitimate reason.

Comment: Not sure what exactly this guy was going for, but it reminds me a bit of ServiceStack.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what he means by "new paradigm." Does he mean in-house or common practice? Because I don't think it is a common practice.

The typical thing you'd see is

```
service.Handle(IRequest request);
```

But it some cases, in order to handle the request, the service needs access to private variables, so you could invert, with the help of a dependency that is injected *into the method* (and not the class), like this:

```
request.Handle(IService service);
```

...which allows the request to drive any data transfer, possibly copying private variables into parameters in the service method. This would normally be pretty lightweight, e.g.

```
class Request
{
    public void Handle(IService service)
    {
        service.doSomething(_somePrivateField, _someOtherField);
    }
}
```

...so that the true logic remains in the service. It's a slight stretch but this sort of thing doesn't really violate SRP because it is still the service that knows how to process the data; the Request is just responsible for storing and transfering data. Not unreasonable.

But this?

```
var request = new Request(IService service, IOther other, etc.)
request.Handle();
```

...seems very unusual to me. You ought to be able to instantiate a request and work on it without instantiating and passing in a ton of dependencies, because it's very possible you won't end up submitting the request at all, e.g. if it doesn't pass validation.

I guess maybe if Request also has the responsibility of validating itself, and it needs the service and other dependencies in order to do that (e.g. `AddUserRequest` might need to know how to check if a user with the same user name already exists), then maybe you'd have to do it this way. Personally I don't-- that kind of validation would take place in the business layer or data layer.  It does seem to inflate your dependency graph and bend the rules when it comes to SRP. In my humble opinion.

Sorry I don't have a solid answer (seems like this sort of thing is similar to [rich versus anemic domain model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314330/rich-vs-anemic-domain-model) debate, which is unresolved) but I hope this answer helps.